# Import local module in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

A very basic questions on importing modules created locally.

I am unable to import a locally created module. The module exists in the current working directory

[image]

[image]

Am i missing something?

Comment: If your module is in a folder you'll have to do `from foldername.myModule import Person`

Comment: The current working directory of the notebook server is the base path where you started the server. How about --  import sys sys.path.append("path to your module")

Comment: It is not in a separate folder, both the module (to be imported) and the notebook where I am calling or importing the module are on the same path.

Comment: I have created an env. variable PYTHONPATH to set current working directory as the sys path. If I am not mistaked import sys sys.path.append("path to your module")  would do the same.

Comment: try to import in terminal, and let see if you have an error or not.

Comment: got the same error on the terminal

Comment: python -c "import myModule; myModule.interact(local=locals())"

Comment: I was just facing this issue after uploading a .py file to import and none of the zillion solutions on SO worked. So I went back to basics and just restarted the kernel. lo and behold it now works as expected with a simple import statement.

Answer (score 7):

I'm finding local library names must begin with a capital letter. If I keep all my local files in a folder called `Code`, I can import them; if it's called `code`, I cannot. (The names of subfolders and subfiles don't seem to suffer that restriction.)

This appears to be a Jupyter restriction, not a Python one -- from the command-line Python repl I can import whatever local `.py` file I want.

Comment: man, I love you. I have been fighting against an import for hours. I wish I had found your answer hours ago.

Comment: I know the feeling. Today I spent half an hour writing a bug report, only to when filing it have the submission validator inform me similar issues already existed, and in fact it had been submitted twice before, and was already solved in the development branch ... Anyway happy to help.

Answer (score 6):

```
%%capture
%run myModule.ipynb
```

You will get all functions/variables defined in myModule file. This will also overwrite variables of your current notebook but

```
from Mymodule import person
```

has also that effect.

Comment: Are you sure that running the following-
%%capture
%run myModule.ipynb
would also import the variables? I don't think it will. It only imports the functions

Answer (score 5):

```
import os 
#if you want to know current working dir
os.getcwd()
#if you want to change
os.chdir('G:/a-2017-master')
# if you want to list dir
os.listdir()
```

['.DS_Store',
 '.gitignore',
 'cs109a_hw0.ipynb',
 'hwassets',
 'Labs',
 'Lectures',
 'Midterms',
 'Module.py',
 'Projects',
 'README.md',
 'Sections',
 '**pycache**']

```
import os
import Module as m 
a = 10
b = 29
print(f"Addition of {a} and {b} : ",m.add(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the W3schools Tutorial to create module locally:

1. In a conda environmnet keras, 'cookie.py' module is created and jupyter notebook is initiated in the same path. Then create a file named 'Importing_module_locally'.

```html
(keras) ninjawarrior@ninjas-MBP cookiecutter % pwd
/Users/ninjawarrior/miniconda3/environments_files/pythonbasics/Python_Tutorial_w3schools/mymodules/cookiecutter
```

2. Confirming both module and jupyter notebook file is on the same path.

```html
(keras) ninjawarrior@ninjas-MBP cookiecutter % ls -lrt
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 ninjawarrior  staff   46 Oct 12 12:47 cookie.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 ninjawarrior  staff   96 Oct 12 12:50 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 ninjawarrior  staff  751 Oct 12 12:56 Importing_module_locally.ipynb
```

3. Enter the below in cookie.py

```html
def greeting(name):
  print("Hello, " + name)
```

`

4. Enter the below in Import_module_locally

```html
import mymodule                  

mymodule.greeting("Jonathan")
```

Result : Hello, Jonathan

Hope this helps !